# Show that $P(A) = 0\implies P(B) = 0$ if matrix $A$ is similar to matrix $B$ and $P(x)$ is any polynomial.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Note: This is a homework problem.

I've been working on this one for a while now and seem to be a bit stuck. The one thing for sure I know we can say is that $P(A) = P(M^{-1}BM) = 0$

Is there some way to pull the $M^{-1}$ and $M$ out of the equation? Or possibly use $\mathbb{det}(P(M^{-1}))\mathbb{det}(P(A))\mathbb{det}(P(M))$?

Thank you for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: I did not understand the question.... can you try to be a bit more clear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for any monomial, with $B=M^{-1}AM$, we have
$$
a_nB^n=a_n(M^{-1}AM)^n=a_n\underbrace{(M^{-1}AM)(M^{-1}AM)\cdots(M^{-1}AM)}_{n\text{ times}}\\
=a_nM^{-1}A^nM=M^{-1}(a_nA^n)M.
$$
This implies
$$
P(B)=M^{-1}P(A)M\quad\text{and}\quad P(A)=MP(B)M^{-1}
$$
from which your result follows.